# JS (Moo Tools) Slider Not Working in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the below site:
http://kelseydelo.com/

When I click the main nav links in Safari the content slides properly.  However in Chrome and Firefox nothing happens when I click these (no errors in Firebug either).

I believe it used to work in FF so it seems a recent upgrade has broken it.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use mootools 1.2.3 which is old. in 1.2.3, mootools utlised feature detection for browser detection - and in particular, it was a problem with firefox as it relied on the following code:

`if (!document.getBoxObjectFor ...)`

but that method got made obsolete by mozilla. subsequently, in 1.2.5 and 1.3 mootools detection was done so it does not rely on this any more (breaking change was FF 3.6.nn or something)

on your site in FF 4.0 you can run

`console.log(Browser.Engine)`

and it comes back as 'unknown' - which will make any browser-specific hooks and fixes fail.

In Chrome 13 Canary, it detected webkit fine but does not work either so there must be something else -- legacy here... in other words, UPGRADE to 1.3.2 (which uses ua-sniffing) - if noobslide supports it, else go 1.2.5.1